# How to read csv with character and numeric in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, dataset

I have a csv dataset like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY5S1.png)

I tried the following code,

```
% Read GDP dataset
fileID = fopen('GPD.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %f',...
'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
```

But it gives me the following errors,

```
Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
```

So how can I read the data?

Comment: take a look to `csvread`

Comment: `csvread` is not the problem here, `textscan` works just as well. The problem is Matlab cannot find 'GPD.csv' in root directory. You need to put the full path to that file in or it will not be able to find it. Alternatively, add the file to your project space.